# Solving a SHM (Simple Harmonic Motion) with given velocities at specific time

Tags: physics, shared-memory, motion

SHM - Simple Harmonic Motion

A simple harmonic oscillator has a frequency of 6.2 Hz. It is oscillating along x, where x(t) = Acos(wt + d). You are given the velocity at two moments: v(t=0) = 1.9 cm/s and v(t=.1) = -19.4 cm/s.

Calculate A and d.

Since I know that T = 1/f, I found out that T = 0.1612 
And since, W = 2pi / T, w = 38.9557

Can't find out what to do with the velocities ?!

Need help as soon as possible...

Comment: Look at the Physics stack exchange.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about [physics.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 0):

You get

```
v(t) = -A*w*sin(w*t+d)
```

and you know `v(0)=-Aw*sin(d)` as well as `v(t)` for `t=0.1`.

```
v(t) = x'(t) = -A*w*( cos(w*t)*sin(d)+sin(w*t)*cos(d) )
```

so that

```
-A*w*cos(d) = ( v(t)-cos(w*t)*v(0) ) / sin(w*t)
```

and then conversion to polar coordinates will give you the values for `A` and `d`.